# Constructor undefined while using multiple classes

Tags: java, class, constructor

I have a question. For the first time, I am working with multiple classes in JAVA. I have some trouble doing this. I created a class which I will call from another class. I want to make a type `Coordinate`, which, as the name suggests, holds coordinates. then, I want to shift those coordinates. So far the code looks as follows:

```
public class Coordinate {
    double x;
    double y;

    Coordinate(){
        x=0;
        y=0;
    }

    public Coordinate(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        System.out.print(x);//TO TEST WHETHER IT DOES SOMETHING
    }

    Coordinate shiftCoordinate(int z, int w){
        this.x = x + z;
        this.y = y+ w;
        return new Coordinate(x,y);//ERROR: The constructor Coordinate(double, double) is undefined
    }


}
```

It throws an error where stated. I do not understand this error. In my 'main' class, I did the following:

```
void start() {

    Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();
    coordinate.x=3;
    coordinate.y=4; 
}
```

I would expect this to print `3`, but it does not. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The error you mentioned explains exactly what is wrong.  If you want to use the constructor `Coordinate(x,y)`, you have to create it.  No such constructor exists unless you write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you don't work with mutiples class, only one : `Coordinate` but you want multiple constructors.

1. As your attributs are `double` make a constructor that needs that type, it'll be used when you write `new Coordinate(5,6)`

   ```
   public Coordinate(double x, double y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }
   ```
2. If you want a default constructor (no args) it'll be used when you call `new Coordinate()`
3. You want a way to shift from a `Coordinate` instance you have 2 ways  : modify the current instance **or** create a new one, but don't do both together (like your code) it's not usefull to get at the end 2 objects whith the same values

   ```
   // modify current instance
   void shiftCoordinate(double z, double w) {
       this.x = x + z;
       this.y = y + w;
   }

   // return a new object
   Coordinate shiftCoordinate(double z, double w) {
       return new Coordinate(this.x + z, this.y + w);
   }
   ```

---

Also you last code uses the default constructor with no args so that's normal you don't see any printing use `new Coordinate(3,4)` to see it

---

A classic constructor is also, the constructor to clone an instance, it takes an instance and create a new one with the same values :

```
    public Coordinate(Coordinate clone) {
        this.x = clone.x;
        this.y = clone.y;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! So, if I am correct, per class you can only have one constructor. This constructor either takes args or it does not, but you can not have both. Correct?

Comment: @Mathbeginner nope, you can have as many constructor as you want, they just need to take different parameters

Comment: But in my code I have one constructor that takes no args, and one constructor that takes two integers. Than why do I get that error saying that the constructor with that input is undefined?

Comment: @Mathbeginner you have a constructor that takes **ints** and your argument are **doubles**, please read my answer fully and use its code ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Coordinate(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

This constructor has arguments that are integers, and you're trying to pass in doubles. Change the constructor to this:

```
public Coordinate(double x, double y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    System.out.print(x);
}
```